# How to display a progressbar when export data into a file in c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar, data-export

**I have finished the part of export data from database into file,but i find it takes a very very long time to wait for this action finish sometimes.So i want to add a progress bar in my program, but here is my question:

1. i don't know how big the xx.xls file it is
2. i don't know how to get the stage of the file size that had been exported

So i don't have any idea about how to compute the percentage of the progress bar. what should i do to get all the information i need or is there any other solutions?
thanks a lot here is my code of export data:**

```
SaveFileDialog savefiledialog = new SaveFileDialog();
                savefiledialog.FileName = @"data.xlsx";

                if (!(bool)savefiledialog.ShowDialog())
                    return;



                DbHelper dh = new DbHelper("data.mdb");
                ApplicationClass excel = new ApplicationClass();


                Workbooks workbooks = excel.Workbooks;
                Workbook workbook = workbooks.Add();


                Worksheet sheet1 = (Worksheet)excel.ActiveSheet;

                ArrayList itemList = dh.setTable("Item").where("1=1").select();
                sheet1.Cells[1, "A"] = "col1";
                sheet1.Cells[1, "B"] = "col2";
                sheet1.Cells[1, "C"] = "col3";



                int i = 2;
                foreach (Item item in itemList)
                {
                    sheet1.Cells[i, "A"] = item.Website;
                    sheet1.Cells[i, "B"] = item.Shop_id;
                    sheet1.Cells[i, "C"] = item.Title;
                    i++;
                }


                sheet1.Range["A1"].AutoFormat(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRangeAutoFormat.xlRangeAutoFormatClassic1);


                string fileName = string.Format(savefiledialog.FileName, Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory));

                // Save this data as a file
                System.Action<string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string> action = sheet1.SaveAs;
                BackgroundWorker b = new BackgroundWorker();
                sheet1.SaveAs(fileName);

                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(sheet1);

                workbook.Close(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(workbooks);

                excel.Quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with table rows count or just show an indeterminate state saying this would take several minutes. Have you tried Bulk Copy ? this will make your export much faster.